# Bulk converting images from one format to another?

Tags: format, convert, png

I want to convert a batch of images, nearly 100, from jpg to png format. How can I do this without renaming them, but instead actually converting the format?

Comment: Use the `convert` command. No, really. But you will want to rename them from something.jpg to something.png.

Comment: @jos, From your comment I don't understand that what should I do!!

Comment: I wasn't finished editing ;-) First, use the `convert` command on a single .jpg file and see if it works. Then, write a script that loops over the .jpg files and converts them to .png files.

Comment: You not mentioned how can I use the `convert` command on a single .jpg file. And I don't know how to write a script that loops over the .jpg files.

Answer (score 103, accepted):

Try these commands,

```
mogrify -format png /path/*.jpg
```

This will convert all the .jpg files into .png files and saves the converted files in the same directory.

```
mv /path/*.png ~/Desktop/pic
```

This will moves all the `.png` files(converted) to the `pic` directory which resides on the Desktop.

Disclaimer:

If you want to keep the orientation of your image you have to add `-auto-orient` to the command. You can find out why [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/267637/stop-imagemagick-from-rotating-image-on-append). The mogrify command which keeps the orientation  would look like this:

```
mogrify -auto-orient -format png /path/*.jpg
```

Comment: Should I change the directory?

Comment: `/path/*.jpg` represents the directory where the .jpg files are stored.

Comment: I also tried this command after changing the directory: `mogrify -format png .jpg` This also works nicely.

Comment: [The answer below is better](https://askubuntu.com/a/457627/29097), as it takes into account the limits placed on ARGV.

Comment: There is a great guide here: http://www.algissalys.com/how-to/how-to-quickly-rename-modify-and-scale-all-images-in-a-directory-using-linux
Also covers changing the size of the image, which is useful ie. adding
-resize 800x changes longest side to 800 :)

Comment: is `mogrify` command lossless?

Comment: This answer can be done in one line by using mogrify's `-path` option: `mogrify -format png -path ~/Desktop/pic /path/*.jpg`

Comment: @opu the command should be `mogrify -format png *.jpg` not: `mogrify -format png .jpg` After `format`, the next parameter is the format to converted to (in this example: `png`). Then the next param is the file/files (defined by wildcard `*`) that `mogrify` is going to create converted copies from, in this example, the files are determined by `*.png` - the files in current directory ending in `.png` will have converted copies of them created,in jpg format,in this example.Apologies opu that I can't use your full user name in my mention -askubuntu not allowing me to enter the symbol in your name.

Comment: I don't know why but this command flips my image vertically (I'm on Windows).

Comment: it rotates images

Answer (score 64):

**Using ImageMagick**.

First install imagemagick:

```
sudo apt-get install imagemagick
```

Try converting just one image at first:

```
convert image.jpg image.png
```

Now convert all:

```
mogrify -format png *.jpg
```

**EDIT**

You also need to split it into chunks that will fit to avoid hitting the limit of how much you can put on a command line. This should work better:

```
find -name '*.jpg' -print0 | xargs -0 -r mogrify -format png
```

The `-print0` and `-0` are used to handle spaces in filenames and the `-r` means don't run mogrify if there's nothing to do.

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1010261/running-a-batch-with-imagemagick

**EDIT 2**
Switched png and jpg as per @Glutanimate's comment.

**EDIT 3**
Changed png to jpg in last suggestion.

Comment: One image converted successfully. But when I used command to convert all its showing   `mogrify.im6: unable to open image ``*.png': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2638.``mogrify.im6: unable to open file ``*.png' @ error/png.c/ReadPNGImage/3667.`

Comment: You will have to `cd` to that directory first. If they are in the desktop, run `cd ~/Desktop` first then try converting again.

Comment: I changed the directory

Comment: @Parto I think it should be `mogrify -format png *.jpg`. The OP is asking about converting jpg → png.

Comment: did not work for me with 14.04 @Parto

Comment: @talha06 What error did you get?

Comment: sorry, my mistake. It was an issue about the permission. I can confirm it works as it is expected.

Comment: why the first command works but not the second one?  `find . -name '*.png'  -exec mogrify -format -quality 100 jpg *.png {} +` and 2nd one...
 `find . -name '*.png'  -exec convert -units PixelsPerInch  -density 300 -quality 100 jpg *.png {} +`

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, convert works. You don't need to test it. Secondly, a bash oneliner suits the need:

```
$ for file in Ground*jpg; do { \
  echo "Converting $file to `echo $file|cut -d. -f1`.png" ;\
  convert $file `echo $file|cut -d. -f1`.png ; } done
```

Rockin' it auldskewl ;)

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been a long time since this question was put but there is one brilliant piece of software that has not been mentioned that I have used a lot.

http://photobatch.wikidot.com/  also known as Phatch.  It literally converts anything from anything to anything else in image terms.  It had not been updated for a while but now claims to be released for ubuntu 17.10.  Give it a try.  I'm confident you'll be very happy with it.

Comment: Tried to get this software, the "download" link to the deb file is missing from the above link, and the Ubuntu "store" version gave me this error:
Detailed errors from the package manager follow:
apt transaction returned result exit-failed
Ubuntu v 18.10 maybe?  Anyway - my experience.