# How to convert webp to grayscale png?

Tags: convert, tools, png, webp

I have a bunch of webp images and need to convert them to png format. I know png supports different color modes like grayscale which I need.

Is there any Linux tool or online services to achieve this fast and easy?

I tried different online converters, but all of them convert webp to png with default RGB color mode.

Comment: Check this answer https://askubuntu.com/questions/457604/bulk-converting-images-from-one-format-to-another

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bulk converting images from one format to another?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/457604/bulk-converting-images-from-one-format-to-another)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for an online tool with the support of converting to grayscale PNG, this [online WebP to PNG converter by Vertopal](https://www.vertopal.com/en/picture/convert/webp-to-png) will do the trick.

Based on the tools section bottom of the page, it supports 8-bit grayscale:

> Convert WEBP to Black & White (monochrome) PNG, 8-bit Grayscale PNG, 24-bit RGB PNG, and 32-bit RGBA PNG.

I used a WebP image from [Google Developers WebP Gallery](https://developers.google.com/speed/webp/gallery1) for the test:

[Original WebP Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uuws6.jpg)

[Converted to 8-bit grayscale PNG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ZqQS.png)

It worked just fine. Good luck.

Answer (score 7):

This can be done on the command line using the `imagemagick` package. This has the advantage that it becomes easy to script for an entire directory of images (*hint:* either combine with the `find -exec` command or a bash `for` loop).

First install the package:

`sudo apt update && sudo apt install imagemagick`

Download an example *webp* image to test it out on:

```
wget https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/1.webp
```

The imagemagick command:

```
convert 1.webp -colorspace Gray 1.png
```

You should now have a black and white png image in the same directory. *-colorspace Gray* converts the image to black and white.

For more info, try: `man convert`

Answer (score 3):

Use GIMP 2.10.

click  file>open and select open .webp file.
Now go to image>mode>Grayscale
Now go to File>export as and export as yourfilename.webp

and that is your image is converted to grayscale.
While exporting it is upto you if want to select lossless or lossy.

Comment: Wait... there's lossy PNGs?

Comment: No I write about .webp format.

Answer (score 3):

Use **Inkscape 1.1.1**,

Open `.webp` file by click `Open` in `File` menu `[File > Open]`
Now click on `Export PNG Image...` in `File` menu. `[File > Export PNG Image...]`
On the side, in the `Export PNG Image` tab and `Drawing` sub-tab, click on the `Advanced` accordion.
Set `Bit depth` on `Gray_1`, `Gray_2`, `Gray_4`, `Gray_8`, `Gray_16`, `GrayAlpha_8` or `GrayAlpha_16` based on your needs.
Enter `Filename` with `.png` extension and click on `Export` button.

This will convert your webp file to grayscale png.

Comment: Is there a benefit to using Inkscape (optimised for vector graphics) over GIMP for raster file converting between these raster formats?

Comment: @ChrisH Two separate applications offer different settings to the user. However, this is a way to convert `webp` to `png`.

Answer (score 2):

## ffmpeg example

Using the [format filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#format) to set grayscale:

```
ffmpeg -i input.webp -vf format=gray output.png
```

See [FFmpeg & Black and White Conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32385256/) for several other methods.

## Convert an entire directory

Use a Bash *for loop*:

```
for f in *.webp; do ffmpeg -i "$f" -vf format=gray "${f%.*}.png"; done
```

Adapted from [How do you convert an entire directory with ffmpeg?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33766147/)